# Path Translation issue in Asterisk PBX DialPlan

Tags: asterisk, voip

Asterisk Pbx cannot translate path for Calling from Cell to DID. when i call from Cell to My DID Number then  Warning in Pbx occuring

> No path to translate from SIP/1005-000002cc to
> SIP/ForNishantPBX-000002cb
>
> Spawn extension (from_NishantPSTN, 14692498805, 1) exited non-zero on 'SIP/ForNishantPBX-000002cb'

following is my **extensions.conf** configuration for DialPlan:

> ```
> [from_NishantPSTN]
> exten => _14692498805,1,Dial(SIP/1005,20)
> ```

here i am calling from my cell number to DID number: 14692498805, Now at the time of Translation in PBx, i am getting above mentioned Warning & my call cannot be connected.

i need some suggestions to about Dial Plan to make it happen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That message mean you have codecs A,B,C in inbound and D,E,F on outbound and there are no matching codec and no translator which can transcode choosed codec(for example if choosed A+E no translator from A to E )

Usually such situation when you allowed g729 or g732 codec and have no codec_g729.so (which require license,so payed module)

You can solve it by set same allow= on both peers.

Comment: perfect click, that was codec issue only. i gave lower priority to g729  & it works.. thnx..

Comment: In sip set debug also give reason.